# Timezone format in /etc/timezone of Debian 7

Tags: timezone

In my Debian 7 OS:

```
cat /etc/timezone
Asia/Shanghai
```

In one of my friends' Debian 7 OS:

```
cat /etc/timezone 
Etc/UTC
```

Why is it not of the format of Continent/City?

Comment: UTC is not a location, so it is a special case and goes into Etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UTC is considered a valid timezone setting in the tz database. It isn't restricted to just `continent/city`.

You can find a complete [list of valid options in this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).